# changing default environment for assignment of new variables

Tags: r

I often want to create many variables in an environment under the global environment.  This can be done easily with the `envir` argument to `sys.source` -- if all of the variables created by the file that one is sourcing are supposed to go into a single environment.

But I typically work with a file that creates sets of variables.  One set should go into one environment, another set should go into another environment, and so on.  I don't want to split this file into multiple files and then make multiple calls to `sys.source`.

Instead, I would like a command that lets me change the default environment for assignment of new variables.  For example:

```
e <- new.env()
setDefaultEnvironment(e)
tmp <- 2
e$tmp           #  2 
.GlobalEnv$tmp  #  Error: object 'tmp' not found
```

But `setDefaultEnvironment` isn't a real command.

Is there any safe way to do this sort of thing in R?

Comment: Can you provide some detail for why you want to do this

Comment: @Dason -- yes, I updated the original post with some more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `evalq` function will evaluate its first argument in a specified environment, so you could create your new environment, then wrap the assignments into `evalq`.

Answer (score 17):

**It's best to be explicit:** changing global states is dangerous.  Thus:

```
e <- new.env()
with(e, {foo <- bar; foo2 <- bar2})
```

will do the job cleanly, with little fuss, while prominently displaying the environment involved.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps someone can improve on this, removing the need to quote the variable name:

```
e <- new.env()
`%=%` <- function(x,y) {assign(x,y,envir = e)}

"d" %=% 5

e$d
[1] 5
```

But this feels kind of silly to me. Maybe just use `assign` directly? More typing, maybe, but it does what you want with less danger.

Comment: `"%=%" <- function(x,y) {assign(as.character(substitute(x)), y, envir = e)}`  that should allow you do just do `d %=% 5` without the quotes around the d.

Comment: You can even override `=` (and/or `<-`) temporarily. Beware though, it will break all kinds of stuff. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the environment, an easy way to do this is to save all variables in a list. A list works like an environment, as to variables.

```
e <- list()
e$tmp <- 2
```