# Is it possible to save a ggplot in RDS format with a global variable in the ggplot() call?

Tags: r, ggplot2

RDS files are wonderful for sharing R objects between R files. And I often share ggplot objects between R files when I have a particularly complicated layout. Usually this works great.

My grumble is that if your ggplot() function call contains a global variable, that variable is lost when you save the plot as an .rds file. So when you load the plot in a new R file, it's no bueno. Information is lost.

Does anyone know a clever solution for this problem? The work-arounds I have come up with are clunky. And I really don't want to regress to the default save() and load() functions.

How about a few examples. I'll start with a chunk that works. Then I'll show how things fall apart with a global variable.

**NOTE: This code will put a couple junk files in your current working directory. Ye be warned.**

```
# Preliminaries -------------------------------------------
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

# Fake data
x <- 1:5 %>% as.factor()
y <- rnorm(5)
df <- data_frame(x, y)


# First an example that works -----------------------------
# Notice how the color palette is 
# defined within scale_fill_manual()
this_plot_works <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "orange", "green", "purple"))

# Save plot to file
saveRDS(this_plot_works, file = "this_plot_works.rds")

# To simulate the behavior of moving to a new R file
# let's remove the ggplot object from the environment.
rm(this_plot_works)

# Now, pretending we're in a new R file, load the plot
this_plot_works_reloaded <- readRDS("this_plot_works.rds")
this_plot_works_reloaded
```

Now I'll specify the color palette as a global variable, and I'll call it within the ggplot function (I guess, technically, it's called in the 'scale_fill_manual()' function, but you know what I mean). This strategy will not work.

```
# Second example that won't work --------------------------
# Specify color palette as a global variable
col_pal <- c("red", "blue", "orange", "green", "purple")

# Plot
# Note that the color palette is tied to the global variable
this_plot_wont_work <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_pal) 

# Save the plot to file
saveRDS(this_plot_wont_work, file = "this_plot_wont_work.rds")

# Again, let's remove the key global variables
# and pretend we're switching to a new R file
rm(this_plot_wont_work, col_pal)

# Load the plot
this_plot_wont_work_reloaded <- readRDS("this_plot_wont_work.rds")
this_plot_wont_work_reloaded
```

Comment: You could use `CodeDepends::getInputs(call)@inputs` to get the variable inputs to your `ggplot` call, but you'd need to do some more work after that.

Comment: CodeDepends has the `graph` package as a dependency, which is no longer on CRAN. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=graph

Comment: With the benefit of many more years of programming, don't do this. Pass data between scripts, don't pass plots. (Also, I asked this question before the wonderful 'patchwork' library existed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is pretty old but anyway...

You could save the plot and global variables as separate objects:

```
# SAVE PLOT...
saveRDS(this_plot_wont_work, file = 'this_plot_wont_work.rds')

# ...AND GLOBAL VARIABLES
globVar = list(col_pal = col_pal)
saveRDS(globVar, file = 'this_plot_wont_work.bis.rds')
```

Then reload them in the right order (i.e. global variables first)

```
# LOAD GLOBAL VARIABLES RDS NAMED LIST
globRDS = 'this_plot_wont_work.bis.rds'
gglob   = readRDS(globRDS)

# TURN ELEMENTS INTO ACCESSIBLE VARIABLES SO GGPLOT2 HAVE ACCESS TO THEM
# (I.E. LIST(VAR1 = VALUE1) >>> VAR1 = VALUE1)
for (i in seq(length(gglob))){
    assign(x = names(gglob[i]) , value = gglob[[i]])
}

# AND FINALLY LOAD THE GGPLOT OBJECT
plotRDS = 'this_plot_wont_work.rds'
gg = readRDS(plotRDS)

gg
```

Comment: There's no need to save them in separate RDS files, you can put them all into the same file. At any rate, OP seems to be asking how to do this automatically, i.e. without having to manually specify the dependencies.

Comment: @KonradRudolph may I ask how you would save several objects into one RDS file? according to `?saveRDS`: *saveRDS and readRDS provide the means to save a **single** R object ...* https://stackoverflow.com/a/52229310/7941188 suggests to use .RData instead, but maybe you had something else in mind? Really curious to learn, thanks!

Comment: @tjebo Simply stick them in a list, which is what this answer already does *anyway*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph fair enough! makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think one option would be to create the plot and all objects that your plot needs within a new environment. You can then export and import this environment as .Rds as a single object. Once imported into a new session, you can either use that environment or you can also move the objects of that environment into your global environment.

NB: this answer will create files in your working directory

```
## Session 1 - when defining your plot, do this within a new environment 
e <- new.env()
## thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761618/7941188
with(e, {
  set.seed(42)
  df <- data.frame(x = as.character(1:5), y = rnorm(5))
  col_pal <- c("red", "blue", "orange", "green", "purple")
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = x)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = col_pal)
})

saveRDS(e, "plot_and_obj.Rds")

## New session
library(ggplot2)
e <- readRDS("plot_and_obj.Rds")
## call plot either within the environment 
with(e, p)

## Or move all objects from child environment to global env 
## thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/13797968/7941188
list2env(as.list(e), globalenv())
p
```