# Saving several variables in a single RDS file

Tags: r, save, datastore

I want to pass a list of variables to saveRDS() to save their values, but instead it saves their names:

```
variables <- c("A", "B", "C")
saveRDS(variables, "file.R")
```

it saves the single vector "variables".

I also tried:

```
save(variables, "file.RData")
```

with no success

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `list` argument of the `save` function.  EG:

```
var1 = "foo"
var2 = 2
var3 = list(a="abc", z="xyz")
ls()
save(list=c("var1", "var2", "var3"), file="myvariables.RData")
rm(list=ls())
ls()

load("myvariables.RData")
ls()
```

Please note that the `saveRDS` function creates a .RDS file, which is used to save a single R object.  The `save` function creates a .RData file (same thing as .RDA file).  .RData files are used to store an entire R workspace, or whichever names in an R workspace are passed to the `list` argument.

YiHui has a nice [blogpost](https://yihui.name/en/2017/12/save-vs-saverds/) on this topic.

If you have several data tables and need them all saved in a single R object, then you can go the saveRDS route.  As an example:

```
datalist = list(mtcars = mtcars, pressure=pressure)
saveRDS(datalist, "twodatasets.RDS")
rm(list=ls())

datalist = readRDS("twodatasets.RDS")
datalist
```

Comment: I have several big data tables and want to save them all together to a single file and then load them. What would be the option for that purpose?

Comment: You can put the data tables into a list and save them with saveRDS.  I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to store all your variables within a new environment and save this as an Rds file. You can then move the objects of this environment to the global environment (or leave them where they are).

```
e <- new.env()
with(e, {
  var1 = "foo"
  var2 = 2
  var3 = list(a="abc", z="xyz")
})
saveRDS(e, "my_obj.Rds")

## new Session
my_obj <- readRDS("my_obj.Rds")
list2env(as.list(my_obj), globalenv())
```

Comment: I like this approach. And if you dont need a new environment, you can save a few keys strokes by saving directly to a list: `var_list <- list(var1 = "foo", var2 = 2, var3 = list(a = "abc", z = "xyz"))
saveRDS(var_list, "var_list.Rds")
my_obj <- readRDS("var_list.Rds")
list2env(my_obj, envir = .GlobalEnv)`