# How to save multiple .rds files with parallelization efficiently?

Tags: r, doparallel, furrr

I'm applying a function to a different data ~2000 times and I'd like to save .rds after each iteration. I've parallized the code using furrr/foreach, so it's quite efficient at the moment. However, I don't know how to save intermediate results of each iteration and preserve the computation time, at the same time.
So, Is it possible to save multiple .rds in parallel efficiently?

Reproducible example:

```
library(tictoc)
library(future)

plan(multiprocess)

custom_f <- function(x) {
  saveRDS(rep(seq(x:(x+10000), 10000) ), 
          file = paste0(x,'.RDS'), 
          compress = F)
}

tic()
furrr::future_map(1:10, custom_f)
toc()
# 95.38 sec elapsed


tic()
for (i in 1:10){
  custom_f(i)
}
toc()
# 62.93 sec elapsed
```

Comment: Hi , what i understand is you want to save file .rds. Hope this link helps to solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229140/saving-several-variables-in-a-single-rds-file

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Is `saveRDS()` too slow for you? Saving intermediate results will always have a time penalty since it's extra work the computer has to do. You can decrease the time it takes to save an rds with `compress = FALSE` or by using a save function from a different package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58701560/5028841